# creating a formula in google sheets that removes every word from column I that exists in column K

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need help creating a formula that  deletes all the words from column I that exists in column k.

formulas from chatgpt, none worked. It always says that the formula doesnt work. I have also tried this in word excel and not been able to figure out how i should formulate the formula. Would really appreciate if any one has any suggestions or so.

Comment: please provide screenshots and/or a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) where you illustrate the problem you're trying to solve as well as the desired result.

Comment: A formula is NOT going to delete any content. The solution will require an apps script.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

Delete every word in I thats also in K

```
function deleteEveryWordInKThatsInI() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let colK = vs.map(r => r[10]);
  let colI = vs.map((r, i) => [(~colK.indexOf(r[8]) ? "": r[8])]);
  sh.getRange(sr, 9,colI.length,colI[0].length).setValues(colI);
}
```

- [Condtional Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)